# Eclipse JMeter v3.1 implementation of the project error "check JMeterHome and libraries"

Tags: eclipse, jmeter

JMeter official website to download the v3.1 project into the implementation of the operation after the Eclipse error, but JMeter v3.0 normal operation in the Eclipse.

**What is causing the error?**

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read those 2 docs:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/building.html
- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/eclipse.md

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I implemented the "ant install" to solve the problem：）